# Django AWS Elastic Beanstalk migrate database

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying a Django project to AWS using Elastic Beanstalk and am stuck on migrating the database.

**Where I'm at:** I am able to successfully deploy my django project and load the page through mysubdomain.elasticbeanstalk.com. The page loads without error until I get to a page that needs to do a database call. I then get an error like `relation "accounts_user" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "accounts_user"` because my database hasn't been migrated.

**What I've tried:** I've tried quite a few variations of things. Fortunately there are an abundance of stackoverflow posts and a couple tutorials. Unfortunately, they all seem to be using a different version and what they suggest do not apply to my project.

It is pretty clear to me that I need to run the migration in a `foobar.config` file inside the `.ebextensions/` folder. Here is the base of what I want to do:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "python manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
```

In the logs, I see that the post deployment script tried to run but it failed. I don't receive any other info on the error, the only thing I see is something like "ERROR: 01_migrate post deployment script failed"

I find out that I need to activate the virtual environment for the command, which makes sense. From asdf I try this:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python rlg/manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
```

But it doesn't work. In fact, through SSH I find out I don't even have a /opt/python/ folder, only /opt/aws/ and /opt/elasticbeanstalk/. All tutorials and SO questions refer to this folder but I don't have it?

VERSIONS:
Python 3.4.1, Django 1.7.7, AWS CLI 3.2.1, Postgres 9.3

Comment: I'm stuck at the same place. What I found out: the container_commands are NOT executed within the docker container. They are executed on the ec2 instance itself. I guess we have to execute the migration with something like "docker exec [container_name] /var/app/bin/python manage.py migrate --noinput

Unfortunately I'm still struggling finding the correct [container_name]

Comment: @SebastianAnnies awesome, glad I found someone at the same spot! Thanks for the tip I'll be working on that as well and let you know anything I find

Comment: Not sure when this tutorial was written but they have a django migration specific section https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The container_commands are NOT executed within the docker container. They are executed on the ec2 instance directly. 
Currently I'm using `docker exec` to do the migration. As the concerned docker container is afaik the last one started I use `docker ps -a --no-trunc -q | head -n 1` to get the container id.

In the end my setup.config looks like that

```
container_commands:
  01syncdb:
    command: "docker exec `docker ps -a --no-trunc -q | head -n 1` /var/app/bin/python /var/app/manage.py syncdb --noinput  &>> /tmp/deploy.log"
    leader_only: true
  02migrate:
    command: "docker exec `docker ps -a --no-trunc -q | head -n 1` /var/app/bin/python /var/app/manage.py migrate --noinput  &>> /tmp/deploy.log"
    leader_only: true
```

I hope that solves your problem as well.

Comment: Just reading: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=2982
We could have saved ourselves the trouble ...

Comment: I tried this, but I’ve been noticing that it’s getting my old container and not my new one! Has anyone else seen this problem? I was trying a slightly modified, but equivalent command of: `"CONTAINER=\`docker ps -a --no-trunc | grep aws_beanstalk | cut -d' ' -f1 | head -1\` && docker exec $CONTAINER python3 manage.py migrate"`

Comment: This works but will execute the command on the current version, not the staging one (the one currently being deployed) as said @MrCols. Solution provided by nkhumphreys seems to do the trick on the newly deployed version.

Answer (score 16):

I know this is an old post but I want to post my answer here as it took me quite a long time to figure out.

Sebastian kind of pointed me in the right direction but the problem with this approach is it runs before the deployment (so you migrate the old code)

You can also use the `files` command in ebextensions and write a file to /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post but this will run on ever instance

You can combine these two things into:

```
container_commands:
  01migrate:
    command: "mkdir -p /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/ && echo -e '#!/bin/bash\ndocker exec `docker ps -a -q | head -n 1` python <path_to_code> migrate' > /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_migrate.sh && chmod +x /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_migrate.sh"
    leader_only: true
```

This will create a post deploy script in the correct dir and ONLY on the leader.

This is working really well for me but be warned, the hooks directories are un-documented features

Answer (score 0):

## Running migrations from all instances (simple and tested)

The Amazon Linux 2 platform introduced documented hooks for this sort of stuff. Add the following file to your project at `<PROJECT_ROOT>/.platform/hooks/postdeploy/migrate.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

docker exec `docker ps -a -q | head -n 1` python manage.py migrate
```

Here are the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html.

## Running migrations from leader only (untested)

To run migrations only from the leader try something like this:

`.ebextensions/migrate.config`

```
container_commands:
  touch_the_leader:
    command: touch /tmp/migrate
    leader_only: true
```

`.platform/hooks/postdeploy/migrate.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f /tmp/migrate ]; then
    docker exec `docker ps -a -q | head -n 1` python manage.py migrate
    rm /tmp/migrate
fi
```

Answer (score -3):

Updating information regarding latest Elastic Beanstalk version.

I'm using `64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v2.3.3 running Python 3.4`.

The following command works for me without having to activate the `virtualenv` or create a post app deploy hook.

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate_db:
    command: "python manage.py db upgrade" <-- insert your migration command here
    leader_only: true
```

In order to prove that the `container commands` will execute on a post deploy phase, I made a change to my models, generated the updated migrations scripts, deployed the new version and checked to see if the database was successfully migrated: Success!

Comment: That is because you are not running your django app in a Docker container, but rather on python 3.4 image. In a setup with Docker, its different (see comments about running a command within the latest docker container). This is a problem specific to docker environments.