# how to connect Django in EC2 to a Postgres database in RDS?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

First time using AWS services with Django.

Was wondering how to configure the Django app running in a EC2 instance to a Postgres database in RDS?

the EC2 is running ubuntu 14.04

Any special configuration required?

Comment: from time to time I get a plus on the answer below, it would be nice for me and the community if you'd accept the answer even though I assume it did not help you personally (due to time difference)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

All you need to do before doing the normal migration documented in the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/) is to be sure to **have your RDS instance available and accessible to your EC2 instance**.

Then, what you need to do is to modify the `settings.py` file of your app in the `DATABASES` section in the following way:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': '<name defined upon RDS creation>',
    'USER': '<username defined upon RDS creation>',
    'PASSWORD': '<password defined upon RDS creation>',
    'HOST': '<this can be found in "Endpoint" on your RDS dashboard, exclude the ":" and the port number>',
    'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Following this, continue to migrate normally and all should work well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use a deployment service, take a look at at [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/es/documentation/elastic-beanstalk/). It combines EC2, RDS and S3 storage into a Docker and helps keep them together. It's really easy to connect your RDS instance to your EC2 instance(s). I just launched a Django project using that a few weeks ago.

Comment: What you mean by deployment service?

Comment: Amazon has some services that combine groups of services and ease deployment/maintenance (such as EC2 + RDS + S3). There are a couple, but EB was the most straightforward to me, especially with projects written in Python.

Comment: Do you have any good tutorial on this? Particularly for django projects

Comment: I found https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/ to be the best. It's still a little outdated as EB now supports python 3. Also when you get to the section about handling database migrations use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29540131/django-aws-elastic-beanstalk-migrate-database

Comment: I am a Docker newbie and a EB newbie. I found the https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/ not to use Docker. Should I use Docker?

Comment: In addition, Elastic Beanstalk does not appear to let me use Ubuntu 14.04 as the EC2 operating system. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30044609/how-to-use-ubuntu-14-04-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-for-a-python-django-app

Comment: Note that there is a new blogpost covering Python 3 at: https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-and-postgresql-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/