# How to use Ubuntu 14.04 on AWS Elastic Beanstalk for a Python Django app

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I want to ensure that the development environment to work just the same as the production environment. This is to minimise "it works for me" finger-pointing.

Hence my team chose Ubuntu 14.04 as the operating system.

We also want to deploy on AWS.

As I was running through the QwikLabs example on using Elastic Beanstalk, I realized that there is no choice to select Ubuntu 14.04.

[image]

[image]

How do I go about deploying a Django app on a AWS EC2 instance that is running on Ubuntu 14.04?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

AWS limits the operating systems that run under Elastic Beanstalk, as it is [Platform as a Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service). To get full flexibility on operating systems and configuration, you'd need to use EC2.

There are two suboptimal workarounds, though:

- use a Docker instance that is running Ubuntu
- [use this complicated hack to run Ubuntu in EB](http://stormerider.com/blog/2012/08/16/building-an-ubuntu-ami-with-elastic-beanstalk-support/)

Comment: What about using a custom AMI that runs Ubuntu?

Comment: The standard ElasticBeanstalk scripts assume an Amazon Linux system, including the existence of binaries like `rpm`

Comment: AWS now supports custom platforms for EB and, within that, has support for Ubuntu.  See answer I just posted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [set up a custom platform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms.html?icmpid=docs_elasticbeanstalk_console) then tell Elastic Beanstalk to use that platform at creation with `eb create -p YourPlatformARN`.

To confirm, within the linked docs, Ubuntu is supported through their custom platform service:  "... the supported operating systems—Ubuntu, RHEL, or Amazon Linux ..."

Comment: As of 2023 Custom Platform is no longer supported. On July 18,2022, Elastic Beanstalk set the status of all platform branches based on Amazon Linux AMI (AL1) to retired. This includes custom platforms. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms.html?icmpid=docs_elasticbeanstalk_console