# apt-get with CloudFormer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to deploy a software on AWS using CloudFormation. But I have a feeling it is deploying Amazon Linux Instances which has yum package manager. I need apt-get to run on the  my instance so I can run the scripts that I already have. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: As far as I'm aware apt-get is specific to ubuntu so this question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30044609/how-to-use-ubuntu-14-04-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-for-a-python-django-app

Comment: how about deploying Ubuntu instead of Amazon Linux? Trying to use deb packages with a non-deb distro is a terrible idea.

Comment: @Clarkie I am trying to deploy software using CloudFormation. With CloudFormation I can deploy a whole stack of instances for my software. But ElasticBeastalk does really help me. It just launches 1 instance. Anywat, using docker to deploy using Beanstalk? I am not that desperate. Haha.

Comment: @tedder42 You are right. That was a terrible idea. That's why I spent most of the week trying to find a way to deploy Ubuntu Linux instances. And I have found a workaround. Check my comments below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the workaround. It was a long shot but it worked for me. It wasn't really a workaround, I just didn't see it.

When using CloudFormer template, for creating an instance we have to provide an ImageId for it.

```
{
   "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
   "Description" : "Some Description",
   "Resources" : {
      "MyEC2Instance" : {
         "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
         "Properties" : {
            "ImageId" : "ami-79fd7eee",
            "KeyName" : "testkey"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

As you can see, here we are providing ImageId in the properties. So, what I did is very simple. I have deployed my software in an EC2 instance manually. I took the image of the EC2 instance. Now I have a AMI for which I have a unique ImageId. I give this Image ID in the properties right here and Voila! My instance is running and I didn't even have to write any complicated scripts where I have to upload the source code, build it etc.,.

CloudFormation provides helper scripts which will help you run commands immediately after boot of instance. You can use them to make any custom changes to your instance which is made from AMI. For that you might wanna check out this link.
  https://commscentral.net/tech/?post=50

If you do this, your autoscaling will be faster as you have the AMI with everything installed in it. And your development time is saved. A lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think its Possible to add Run apt commands , Try to follow this [Link](http://everyday-tech.com/apt-get-on-centos/).

1.)  Check your System Architecture

uname -i
1
uname -i

2.)  Then download the appropriate .rpm File from below

## For Example....

## wget http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm

3.)  Install RPMForge

rpm -i rpmforge-release-0.5.*.rpm
1
rpm -i rpmforge-release-0.5.*.rpm

4.)  Install apt

yum install apt
1
yum install apt

5.)  Then update your apt Repositories

sudo apt-get update
1
sudo apt-get update

Comment: This is not a valid answer. Can you put details of how to actually solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: @kush-vyas Hey, thanks for the tip bro. But I really didn't want to deploy a Amazon Linux instance. When I asked a workaround, I meant I want a workaround for deploying Ubuntu Linux. But thanks. Now atleast I know I can use apt on Centos.