# Deploy-time commands inside Docker on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, docker

I have a Django service running inside Docker that I deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I would like to run my database migrations at deploy-time

If I were deploying to EB as "a Python project", I could have the following in my `.ebextensions`:

```
$ cat .ebextensions/01run.config 
container_commands:
    01migrate:
        command: "python manage.py migrate --noinput"
        leader_only: true
```

However, `container_commands` are for the EC2 instances - and it's *inside the Docker container* that I have my code etc.

### Things I've already looked at

- I can't just add it to my `Dockerfile`, because applying migrations is all about operating on the attached RDS instance (supplied by the environment) - not really "part of building the Docker image"
- There doesn't seem to be anything useful I can add to `Dockerrun.aws.json`

### Hacky options I've identified so far

- I could perhaps identify the Docker image name inside my `container_commands` and then do `docker run -ti $container-name python manage.py migrate` etc., but no idea how and it feels awfully hacky
- I could run the migrations by hand
- I could replace `CMD gunicorn $etc` with `CMD $script`, where `$script` applies migrations and then starts gunicorn.

  - This is the least awful thing I've identified so far, and what I'm about to do as a stopgap measure.
  - This means "try to apply migrations every time I *start* an instance" which does not leave me comfortable and happy.

Ideas very much welcomed please!

Comment: This could perhaps be what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/29566028/1048839

Comment: Sorry if i'm too late, but placing a script `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre` here will execute the script before deploying, and `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post` will execute it after deploy, if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a post deploy script in your .ebextensions like so:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/10_migrate.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      if [ -f /tmp/leader_only ]; then
        echo "Running Migrations"
        container_id=`docker ps -q --no-trunc --filter label="com.amazonaws.ecs.container-name=MY_CONTAINER_NAME" | head -n 1`
        docker inspect $container_id
        docker exec $container_id /entrypoint.sh python manage.py migrate --noinput
      fi
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/90_rm_leader_only.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      if [ -f /tmp/leader_only ]; then
        echo "Deleting leader_only file"
        rm /tmp/leader_only
      fi
container_commands:
  01_touch_the_leader:
    command: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      touch /tmp/leader_only
    leader_only: true
```

I have included the leader only bit in case you might be using a load balanced environment, it won't run migrations on multiple servers at once.  This can also be used for the `collectstatic` command.

Comment: If you are using a single container docker setup in Elastic Beanstalk you can run you migrate command like this:

sudo docker exec $(sudo docker ps -q) ./manage.py migrate --noinput

Comment: Can confirm that this approach is working for Elastic Beanstalk Multi-container Docker (Amazon Linux/2.20.2).

Comment: Note that for recent AMI's one should use a different directory structure, based on the new hooks : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

Answer (score 0):

I think using [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#entrypoint) in Dockerfile might solve your problem.

Either you can have a script (which takes care of database migrations, starting a webserver and other sanity checks) baked within your container-image and call that script in Dockerfile *ENTRYPOINT*.

```
ADD run_all /opt/bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/bin/run_all"]
```

This way the script is executed only when you create a container of that image.

Or run the both the commands (Python manage.py migrate && httpd start) using *ENTRYPOINT*

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're suggesting either doing it at container build time (which I don't want), or my `$script` suggestion? (I'm not clear on the merits of using `ENTRYPOINT` over `CMD` like you say...?)

Comment: My bad, I haven't read the "CMD $script" point in your question. Its essentially the same, so the answer doesn't apply as you don't want to run the command every time the container starts.

Answer (score 0):

Know this is an old post, but this also works for me, similar approach to what you mentioned as tacky:

```
    container_commands:
      01-init-elb:
        command: "docker exec docker_js_api_1 bash -c 'php artisan optimize:clear && php artisan migrate --force'"
```